# How to use NSURLSession's dataTaskWithURL with Swift 2?

Tags: nsurlsession, swift2, xcode7, nserror

While using Swift 1 this code worked fine:

```
        let connectionSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let task = connectionSession.dataTaskWithURL(currentURL!,  completionHandler:  { (data, response , error) in
            ...
```

In Swift 2 I am getting the following compiler error:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _, _) throws ->
>   _' to non-throwing function type '(NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void'

How can I fix this?

Comment: There is no `try` in Swift 1, how could hat code have worked fine?

Comment: Ups, I was copying from one of my experiments... now question is fixed.

Comment: task!.resume() was already used with Swift 1

Comment: That code fragment does not cause a compiler error in Swift 2. Perhaps the problem is within the completion handler. Please show a (small) complete self-contained example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @MartinR Bingo! I had a problem inside with try / catch. Cheers!

Comment: Please update your *question* with the relevant information (and accept a helpful answer or post your own answer). – Otherwise this thread has no value for future readers and we can close it as off-topic: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*

Answer (score 1):

To use `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` within the completion handler, you will need catch errors:

```
    do {
        var jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray
        // Do Stuff
    } catch {
        // handle error
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use with the optional values like that

```
 var task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        (NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) throws -> Void

           do {
             var jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,options: .MutableContainers) as! NSArray

           } catch {
          // handle error
           }
 }

 task!.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

As @MartinR pointed out, it turned out that the problem was not in the call of NSURLSession's dataTaskWithURL but deep down in the completion handler (more specifically, one of the added during the Swift 1 -> Swift 2 conversions 'try' had not corresponding catch). I have seen others also having similar problems (questions at personal blogs) and will file enhancement request to the Swift folks for better error description.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 2, XCode 7, Apple replaced NSError with ErrorType in several APIs (not all).

You probably use NSError in your own code explicitly. Replace your own NSError usage with ErrorType where Apple uses ErrorType.